# SQL function to sum values/totalize volumes over specific time periods

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the total volume of water irrigated over a section of land.  What I have is the change of flow at an instant of time recorded into a SQL database. -this is measured in cubic meters per hour.

```
Date  Time          Flow Value
2009/10/22 04:00:00.0 0
2009/10/22 04:00:16.2 23
2009/10/22 04:00:20.6 34
2009/10/22 04:00:39.7 95
2009/10/22 04:00:41.7 97
2009/10/22 04:01:15.1 110
2009/10/22 04:03:17.0 95
2009/10/22 04:06:53.8 82
2009/10/22 04:26:50.7 77
2009/10/22 04:36:50.8 76
2009/10/22 04:46:51.7 72
2009/10/22 04:56:52.2 74
2009/10/22 05:16:52.7 72
2009/10/22 05:26:53.2 70
2009/10/22 05:36:22.1 84
2009/10/22 05:46:16.3 81
2009/10/22 05:56:16.2 75
2009/10/22 06:16:17.3 73
2009/10/22 06:26:16.9 75
2009/10/22 06:36:17.7 71
2009/10/22 06:57:38.7 57
2009/10/22 06:57:48.9 44
2009/10/22 06:57:53.4 28
2009/10/22 06:57:55.3 12
2009/10/22 07:07:55.1 0
```

Its simply not the case jut to sum up the values and assume that is the total volume of water irrigated.

what needs to be done is work out the time difference per time stamp and calculate the volume for that time duration, and then have it over the hour(s) the user has selected.

so for the above data, then the time difference would be (for the first hour)

```
time  diff volume
00:00:04.4 101.20
00:00:19.1 649.40
00:00:02.0 190.00
00:00:33.5 3249.50
00:02:01.9 13409.00
00:03:36.8 20596.00
00:19:56.9 98145.80
00:10:00.1 46207.70
00:10:00.9 45668.40
00:10:00.5 43236.00
00:20:00.5 88837.00
00:10:00.5 13521.60
```

There for the total volume irrigated of that hour (from 4am to 5am) is : 373811.6 cubic meter's of water divided by 3600 = 103.8365556

The question is: How do I do this with SQL - I am totally lost, and do not know where to begin, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using SQL Server.  Your sample "for the first hour" actually includes more than the first hour; it should stop after the 00:10:00.1 row I'd think.

You can find the previous row for each row by joining the table on itself, then joining another time, and then saying nothing can be between the first two rows:

```
select 
    StartDate = prev.date
,   EndDate = cur.date
,   Milliseconds = datediff(ms,prev.date,cur.date)
,   Volume = datediff(ms,prev.date,cur.date) / 1000.0 * prev.flow
from @flow cur
inner join @flow prev
    on prev.date < cur.date
left join @flow inbetween
    on prev.date < inbetween.date
    and inbetween.date < cur.date
where inbetween.date is null
```

This gives you the sum per period.  Calculating the hour total requires you to split entries that cross an hour boundary.  You can do that by adding an entry for the end of each hour, like:

```
select date, flow
from @flow
union
-- Add end of hour
select DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, date)+1, 0), flow
from @flow 
where date in (select max(date) from @flow group by datepart(hh,date))
```

You can combine both queries using the WITH statement to calculate the sum per hour:

```
;with FlowWithHourBounds as (
    select date, flow
    from @flow
    union
    -- Add end of hour
    select DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, date)+1, 0), flow
    from @flow 
    where date in (
        select max(date) from @flow group by datepart(hh,date))
)
,  FlowPerPeriod as (
    select 
        StartDate = prev.date
    ,   EndDate = cur.date
    ,   Milliseconds = datediff(ms,prev.date,cur.date)
    ,   Volume = datediff(ms,prev.date,cur.date) / 1000.0 * prev.flow
    from FlowWithHourBounds cur
    inner join FlowWithHourBounds prev
        on prev.date < cur.date
    left join FlowWithHourBounds inbetween
        on prev.date < inbetween.date
        and inbetween.date < cur.date
    where inbetween.date is null
)
select datepart(hh,StartDate), sum(Volume)
from FlowPerPeriod
group by datepart(hh,StartDate)
```

The result is:

```
hour volume
4    285340,5
5    273288,5
6    255408,3
7    5701,2
```

Here's the sample dataset I created from your post:

```
declare @flow table ([date] datetime, flow float)
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:00:00.0', 0  )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:00:16.2', 23 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:00:20.6', 34 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:00:39.7', 95 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:00:41.7', 97 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:01:15.1', 110)
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:03:17.0', 95 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:06:53.8', 82 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:26:50.7', 77 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:36:50.8', 76 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:46:51.7', 72 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 04:56:52.2', 74 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 05:16:52.7', 72 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 05:26:53.2', 70 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 05:36:22.1', 84 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 05:46:16.3', 81 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 05:56:16.2', 75 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 06:16:17.3', 73 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 06:26:16.9', 75 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 06:36:17.7', 71 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 06:57:38.7', 57 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 06:57:48.9', 44 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 06:57:53.4', 28 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 06:57:55.3', 12 )
insert into @flow values ('2009/10/22 07:07:55.1', 0  )
```

Comment: Thanks, Andomar
This should get me started.  But one last question - How does one specify a start and stop date, as the data I have spans over months - I would like to have two variable whereby the user can select the start and stop date where the data can be processed into your result format

Thanks

Comment: Add a where statement like "where date between '2009/01/01 00:00:00' and '2009/02/01 00:00:00'" to the query

Comment: How Does one add "the begin of an hour"?, for instance the data I gave had a Zero value for exactly the turn of the hour ('2009/10/22 04:00:00.0', 0) but what if that value did not exist.  what happens if I only have a value at '2009/10/22 04:00:16.2', 23 -- somehow I must assume that the previous turn of the hour is Zero, and use that to start with - any ideas how this can be added?

Comment: If you assume the hour starts with zero flow, you can safely omit it, since it will not contribute to the total flow?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH    differences
          AS (
              SELECT    s.dt AS dt_start
                       ,MIN(e.dt) AS dt_end
                       ,DATEDIFF(ms, s.dt, MIN(e.dt)) / 1000.0 AS seconds
              FROM      so1608779 AS s
              INNER JOIN so1608779 AS e
                        ON e.dt > s.dt
              GROUP BY  s.dt
             ),
        results1
          AS (
              SELECT    differences.*
                       ,so1608779.flow
                       ,so1608779.flow * differences.seconds AS volume
                       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY differences.dt_start) AS row
              FROM      differences
              INNER JOIN so1608779
                        ON so1608779.dt = differences.dt_start
             )
    SELECT  *
           ,(
             SELECT SUM(volume)
             FROM   results1 AS x
             WHERE  x.row <= results1.row
            ) AS running_total
    FROM    results1
```

Comment: This appears to compute the running total correctly, but it does not compute the volume per hour?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how they wanted to interpolate to find the final part of the hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

```
declare @table table (_time datetime, flow int)

insert into @table
select '04:00:00.0', 0
union select '04:00:16.2', 23
union select '04:00:20.6', 34
union select '04:00:39.7', 95
union select '04:00:41.7', 97
union select '04:01:15.1', 110
union select '04:03:17.0', 95
union select '04:06:53.8', 82
union select '04:26:50.7', 77
union select '04:36:50.8', 76
union select '04:46:51.7', 72
union select '04:56:52.2', 74
union select '05:16:52.7', 72
union select '05:26:53.2', 70
union select '05:36:22.1', 84
union select '05:46:16.3', 81
union select '05:56:16.2', 75
union select '06:16:17.3', 73
union select '06:26:16.9', 75
union select '06:36:17.7', 71
union select '06:57:38.7', 57
union select '06:57:48.9', 44
union select '06:57:53.4', 28
union select '06:57:55.3', 12
union select '07:07:55.1', 0

select t1._time time_start, t2._time time_finish, t1.flow
from @table t1, @table t2
where t2._time = (select min(_time) from @table where _time > t1._time)
```

This will return you the interval in one row and the value:

```
time_start  time_finish flow
04:00:00.000    04:00:16.200    0
04:00:16.200    04:00:20.600    23
04:00:20.600    04:00:39.700    34
04:00:39.700    04:00:41.700    95
04:00:41.700    04:01:15.100    97
04:01:15.100    04:03:17.000    110
04:03:17.000    04:06:53.800    95
04:06:53.800    04:26:50.700    82
04:26:50.700    04:36:50.800    77
04:36:50.800    04:46:51.700    76
04:46:51.700    04:56:52.200    72
04:56:52.200    05:16:52.700    74
05:16:52.700    05:26:53.200    72
05:26:53.200    05:36:22.100    70
05:36:22.100    05:46:16.300    84
05:46:16.300    05:56:16.200    81
05:56:16.200    06:16:17.300    75
06:16:17.300    06:26:16.900    73
06:26:16.900    06:36:17.700    75
06:36:17.700    06:57:38.700    71
06:57:38.700    06:57:48.900    57
06:57:48.900    06:57:53.400    44
06:57:53.400    06:57:55.300    28
06:57:55.300    07:07:55.100    12
```

After this you can use it like subquery and make some multiplications and sum.

Of course it's a simplified example.