# calculate total login logout time in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

```
mysql> select * from timing;

+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| employeeIdNo | employeeLogTime     | employeeLogType |
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|            1 | 2011-08-16 14:59:08 | login           |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 15:00:06 | logout          |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 15:14:51 | login           |
|            2 | 2011-08-16 15:15:00 | login           |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 15:59:01 | logout          |
|            2 | 2011-08-16 15:59:09 | logout          |
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

I want to display the total working time of employee using above data. so i want a mysql query to calculate the total time of(say) employeeIdNo=1. my table name is timing and employeeIdNo is the foreign key references from table employee. after calculation it should return me the totalLogTime value = 00:45:52(this is approx. value, i didnt calculated it exactly). please provide me with appropriate query. thanks in advance.

i tried this query.:-

```
mysql> SELECT 
  TIMEDIFF(FIRSTTIME.employeeLogTime,SECONDTIME.employeeLogTime) 
  FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM timing HAVING employeeLogTime = max(employeeLogTime)) as FIRSTTIME,     
    (SELECT * FROM timing ORDER BY employeeLogTime LIMIT 1,1) as SECONDTIME);
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

its giving me empty set as shown above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [t-sql Summing differences between timestamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609075/t-sql-summing-differences-between-timestamps)

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you sum all times for a single user :

- for login (in milliseconds) call this A
- for logout (in milliseconds) call this B

and return B - A ;

It's a bit ackward as a way to see it but gives much simpler sql queries.
You also need to check that login and logouts have same number of occurences with this method.

Comment: i agree but can u please provide me mysql query for d above.

Comment: Only counting the logins and logouts won't work, you'd also must ensure that they match up (ie that you have matching logout for each login)

Comment: i dont want to count logins and logouts. i want mysql query for total time of a particular employee with employeeIdNo='x'.

Comment: @akshay I understand, I was commenting on Snicolas statement "You also need to check that login and logouts have same number of occurences with this method". This is not enough, you get right sum only if you subtract the sum on **matching** logins and logouts.

Comment: k, sorry.. but i got the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
select employeeIdNo,
sum(loginTimeInSec) as loginTimeInSec
from(
    select 
        e1.employeeIdNo, 
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(e2.employeeLogTime,e1.employeeLogTime)) as loginTimeInSec
    from 
       timing e1 join timing e2
       on e1.employeeIdNo = e2.employeeIdNo
       and e1.employeeLogType = 'login'
       and e2.employeeLogType = 'logout'
       and e1.employeeLogTime < e2.employeeLogTime
       group by e1.id having min(e2.employeeLogTime - e1.employeeLogTime)
) temp
group by employeeIdNo;
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `employeeLogType` column by changing `login` to `1` and `logout` to `0`.
The table will look like:

```
mysql> select * from timing;
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| employeeIdNo | employeeLogTime     | employeeLogType |
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|            1 | 2011-08-16 14:59:08 | 1               |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 15:00:06 | 0               |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 15:14:51 | 1               |
|            2 | 2011-08-16 15:15:00 | 1               |
|            1 | 2011-08-16 15:59:01 | 0               |
|            2 | 2011-08-16 15:59:09 | 0               |
+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Query to display total time of all employees:

```
mysql> SELECT employeeIdNo, time(sum(employeeLogTime*(1-2*`employeeLogType`)))
FROM timing GROUP BY employeeIdNo;
```

Query to display total time of particular employee:

```
mysql> SELECT employeeIdNo, time(sum(employeeLogTime*(1-2*`employeeLogType`)))
FROM timing where employeeIdNo=(employeeIdNo) GROUP BY employeeIdNo;
```

Comment: Hi @Akshay if possible, can you explain, how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Check dis

```
SELECT employeeIdNo ,sec_to_time(SUM(TIME))  FROM
(
    SELECT 
        TO_SECONDS(employeeLogTime     ) * -1 AS TIME
    FROM connection
    WHERE employeeLogType = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 
        TO_SECONDS(employeeLogTime     ) * 1  AS TIME
    FROM connection
    WHERE employeeLogType = 0
) t
;
```