# Query Mysql for select in 1 column but have 2 different type data

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table like this

```
id|Date      |Username|TimeLogin|Type  
1 |2018-01-22|tester1 |07:00    |Login 
2 |2018-01-22|tester1 |22:00    |Logout
3 |2018-01-22|user2   |08:00    |Login
4 |2018-01-22|user2   |18:00    |Logout
```

I want the result to be like this where `Type` being `Login` is made into one column and the `Logout` entry is made into another column in the result.

```
username|logintime|logouttime|date    
tester1 |07:00    |22:00     |2018-01-22    
user2   |08:00    |18:00     |2018-01-22
```

i try this query but the result it's not correct

```
SELECT
    username,
    CASE WHEN type = 'Login' THEN 
        timeLogin
    END AS 'loginTime',
    CASE WHEN type = 'Logout' THEN 
        timeLogin
    END AS 'logoutTime',
    Date
FROM 
    sys_transaksi
WHERE 
    Date = '2018-01-22'
GROUP BY username
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you able to change the table architecture? I highly recommend creating a login time, and a logout time on the same table, and simply keep track of the sessions that way. When the user logs out, just update the table with the logout time for that row for that session. Would be a lot easier than a fairly complex query.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535533/sql-time-difference-within-single-table?rq=1) will likely get you going in the correct direction, if you choose to not take the above suggestion.

Comment: thank for comment, i can't change table architecture, coz i don't have permission for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain something close to the expected result by doing an inner join as illustrated below:

```
SELECT A.username, A.timeLogin `loginTime`, B.timeLogin `logoutTime`, A.date
FROM 
   (SELECT username, `date`, max(timeLogin) timeLogin 
   FROM sys_transaksi WHERE type='login' AND `date`='2018-01-22'
   GROUP BY username, `date`) A
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT username, `date`, max(timeLogin) timeLogin 
   FROM sys_transaksi WHERE type='logout' AND `date`='2018-01-22'
   GROUP BY username, `date`) B 
ON A.username=B.username AND A.timeLogin<B.timeLogin;
```

This gives the most recent login and logout time of each user for a specified date. It will be better to modify the structure of your table, so as to manage the login and logout time of each user session as @FrankerZ proposes in his comments.